# Visualise legend colors in data with outliers in Complexheatmap in R?

Tags: r, legend, heatmap

This is the legend image of a heatmap that i had plot. I have data with a few outliers and thus the range lies from 1-5597. However, the majority of numbers lie in the range of 1-500 but because of few outliers, the colors in the range of 1-500 are not visible. How to visualize legend in case of outliers. Since there are a lot of zero values in my data, i didnt convert it in log scale

```
library(circlize)

col_fun = colorRamp2(c(0,1, 50, 5597),c("#BCE784","#5DD39E", "#348AA7", "#525174"))#c("#EAE0CC","#C9ADA1","#4D6A6D"))# 
lgd = Legend(col_fun = col_fun, 
             title = "Frequency",
             direction = "horizontal",
             legend_width = unit(6, "cm"),
             at = c(1, 50, 100, 1000, 3000,5000))
pushViewport(viewport(width = 0.9, height = 0.9))
grid.rect()  # border
draw(lgd, x = unit(1, "cm"), y = unit(1, "cm"), just = c("left", "bottom"))
popViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to plot? Are you actually plotting a heatmap? Is a logarithmic transformation helpful? Could you convert your outliers to NA for plotting purposes?

Comment: I cannot convert outliers to NA, because i have to represent those cases in heatmap as well. I thought of taking log values, but there are a lot of 0 values in my data